# cordova-plugin-file-transfer is not working in ios build

Tags: ionic-framework

The following build commands failed:

```
/Users/RK/Documents/IONIC/ionic/wema-test/platforms/ios/wemalife-app/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

“@ionic-native/file-transfer”: “^5.27.0”,

“cordova-plugin-file-transfer”: “^1.7.1”,
```

build fail in ios

Ionic:

> Ionic CLI : 5.4.16 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic) Ionic Framework
> : ionic-angular 3.9.2 @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

> Cordova CLI : 10.0.0 Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.0 Cordova Plugins :
> cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

> cordova-res : not installed native-run : not installed

System:

```
ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS : v12.18.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.14.6
OS : macOS Catalina
Xcode : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708
```

Reply

Answer (score 2):

Open the error file.

> /Users/RK/Documents/IONIC/ionic/wema-test/platforms/ios/wemalife-app/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m

Remove lines 107 and 110.

```
NSString* userAgent = [self.commandDelegate userAgent];
if (userAgent) {
[req setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
}
```

Try compiling again, it will compile.

Comment: Could you please add some description? Why should it compile now, for instance.

Comment: This is how i solved this problem.

Comment: Crazy enough, this worked.  I'm need to run this through a bunch of tests to see if there are bigger problems, but everything compiled.  Thanks for the post.