# ionic3 Cordova build ios issue with file transfer plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I update my Cordova ios to version 6 because of apple email that says ( Deprecated API Usage - existing app that use UIWebView are no longer accepted) ,but after that i keep getting this build error,

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/moesaif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/مفسر_أحلامي-epzhtxsuxnuafngaxollgqmkcrww/Build/Intermediates.noindex/مفسر\ أحلامي.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/مفسر\ أحلامي.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o /Users/moesaif/Desktop/Dreams/platforms/ios/مفسر\ أحلامي/Plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

ionic Cordova platform ls :
Installed platforms:
android 7.1.4
browser 6.0.0
ios 6.1.1
Available platforms:
electron ^1.0.0
osx ^5.0.0
windows ^7.0.0

any help please..!
Thanks.

Comment: [I answered in this link. You have to follow the instruction in your **CDVFileTransfer.m** file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265934/cordova-plugin-file-transfer-is-not-working-in-ios-build/69014879#69014879)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the plugin to latest version. If it still uses UIWebView, then you need to update it manually to support WKWebView.

Comment: i have the latest version 1.7.1

Comment: git clone -> modify the code (remove UIWebView usage and use WKWebView), then install it from the local path.

Comment: Or use my fork which is already updated: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-file-transfer`

Comment: ok i forked the plugin with no build errors but when i uploaded the build apple send me invalid binary email again!!

Comment: cordova plugin ls
✔ Running command - done!
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.2-dev "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-inapppurchase 1.1.0 "In App Purchase"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"

Comment: cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.2 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-purchase 10.3.0 "Purchase"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.6.0 "Twitter Connect"

Answer (score 0):

cordova-plugin-file-transfer is deprecated and seems not working with the ios@6.1.1 .

I still use it with ios@5.1.1 and the flag in config.xml to use WKWebview:

`<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />`

Before sending to apple, search and check in Xcode, that you don't have any mention to UIWebview.
Sometimes a clean platforms is needed or you still have and old InAppBrowser version

Comment: How can i search and check mention to uiwebview in xcode!?

Comment: Try that https://stackoverflow.com/a/10583172/1439165. I remember I get the difference between setting true or false, but you can also upload the ipa and see if you get the notification email.